# Test Method to check the error message is displayed in a certain scenario

Tags: apex, unit-test, error-messages

I got this test method written,

```
    static testMethod void test_ValidateImpactCategories(){
            Test.startTest();
            tester();
            ic8 = new Category__c(Name = 'HR',Symbol__c = '?', Justification__c='Target', Risk__c='Cost', Units__c = 'test', Scheme__c = ss.id);
            insert ic8;
            ic9 = new Category__c(Name = 'HR',Symbol__c = '?', Justification__c='Target', Risk__c='Cost', Units__c = 'test', Scheme__c = ss.id);
            insert ic9;

//In above two insertions both Risk__c ='Cost' so in this scenario I want to check the error message(Which is in a custom label) is displayed and add assertions too.

            Test.stopTest(); 
        }
```

Please refer to the comment in the method. I need to check if the error is displayed in the provided scenario. And also I need to add Assertions as well. How to do this in this test method ?

Comment: Is the error message from the custom label being added to the field or SObject in a trigger using `addError`?

Comment: Yes. That's how I use it in the trigger

Comment: here's the code bit. Category.Risk__c.adderror(label.Risk_validation_in_Category);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Errors added in triggers can be detected in tests by catching the exception that occurs when the DML is done and custom labels can be accessed via `Label` in Apex code so the test could look like this:

```
static testMethod void test_ValidateImpactCategories(){
    Test.startTest();
    tester();
    // Insert first 'Cost' category
    insert new Category__c(Name = 'HR',Symbol__c = '?', Justification__c='Target', Risk__c='Cost', Units__c = 'test', Scheme__c = ss.id);
    // Inserting second 'Cost' category should result in an error
    assertErrorOnInsert(
            new Category__c(Name = 'HR',Symbol__c = '?', Justification__c='Target', Risk__c='Cost', Units__c = 'test', Scheme__c = ss.id),
            Label.ErrorMessage
            );
    Test.stopTest();
}

private static void assertErrorOnInsert(SObject sob, String expected) {
    try {
        insert sob;
        System.assert(false, 'exception expected for SObject ' + sob);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.assert(e.getMessage().contains(expected), 'message=' + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code. It looks good to me but i'm getting an error 'Invalid external string name'. I referred to this link, http://www.infallibletechie.com/2014/06/invalid-external-string-name-error-in.html                                 Is there any way I can get rid of this error ?

Comment: @Butterfly Have you changed Label.ErrorMessage to Label.WhataverYourCustomLabelIsCalled?

Comment: That was the bug! Thanks for your help the code works absolutely well and covers my class 100% :)

Comment: if I want to check more scenarios, for example Risk__c = 'Cost' and Risk__c= 'Time', how could it be checked? Is it the same way ?

Comment: @Butterfly Yes. Probably best to have a separate test method per scenario but the idea of having a assertErrorOnInsert method is to re-use it.

Comment: Ok I better try on that then. because when I add more scenarios to the same method it saves but getting a nullpointerException when I run the test.